# Magento 2 compiling SCSS using Gulp

Tags: magento2, css, scss, sass

Currently, our development build uses gulp styles to compile stylesheets for the theme, I've installed it a dozen times but after I attempted to install it today I keep getting stuck on the message `gulpfile not found`

I used these commands to setup node and the correct pyenv versions to install the stylesheets and compile them.

```
brew install node@12 pyenv
brew link node@12 --overwrite
pyenv global 2.7.18
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH
npm config set python ~/.pyenv/shims/python
```

And these are the versions of the pieces I use

```
npm         6.14.14
node        v12.22.4
node-sass  4.13.0 (Wrapper)  [JavaScript]
libsass    3.5.4  (Sass Compiler)    [C/C++]
```

I have completed all steps, and now when I execute `gulp styles` I get this error.

```
No gulpfile found
```

However I do have all the files required to compile my style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after I request help I find the solution. For anyone else having issue's with gulp styles, try to run the following command.

`npm install -g gulp-cli`

If it says the files already exist and your error is still occurring force the installation with the -f attribute.

`npm install -g gulp-cli -f`